# can you edit footers in google Slides using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I have data in a spreadsheet that contain the placeholders and output values that I have linked to the slides template with the same placeholder text. The body of the slides replaces the data however, the footer does not change. Is it possible to edit footers through apps script. If so how do I do it?

```
function onOpen() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Deep Dive')
    .addItem('Create Report', 'executeAll')
    .addToUi();
}

function executeAll() {
 var spreadsheetID= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var spreadsheetFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetID);
  var parentFolder = spreadsheetFolder.getParents();
  var folderID = parentFolder.next().getId();
  var reportTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('FILE ID GOES HERE'); // Gets the report Template
  var copiedTemplate = reportTemplate.makeCopy('New Report', DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID)); //Makes a copy of the orginal and saves it in the specified folder
  var skeleton = SlidesApp.openById(copiedTemplate.getId()); //opens the new template presentation 
  var slides = skeleton.getSlides(); //calls the new slides 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Report Generator'); //gets the data from the active pubfile
  var data = sheet.getRange('Range goes here').getValues();
  data.shift(); //removes the headers in the sheets
  return newSlide1(); 
  

  function newSlide1 () {
    var slide1new = slides[0]; // defining the location of the new slide 1
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide1new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue); //replaces all the text that matches the placeholders
  });
  return newSlide7();
  }
  
  function newSlide7 () {
    var slide7new = slides[6];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide7new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
  return newSlide11();
  }

  function newSlide11 () {
    var slide11new = slides[10];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide11new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
  return newSlide12();
  }

  function newSlide12 () {
    var slide12new = slides[11];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide12new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
  return newSlide14();
  }

  function newSlide14 () {
    var slide14new = slides[13];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide14new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
  return newSlide15();
  }

  function newSlide15 () {
    var slide15new = slides[14];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide15new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });

  return newSlide17();

  }

  function newSlide17 () {
    var slide17new = slides[16];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide17new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
  return newSlide19();

  }

  function newSlide19 () {
    var slide19new = slides[18];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide19new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
  return newSlide20();
  }

  function newSlide20 () {
    var slide20new = slides[19];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide20new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
  return newSlide24();
  }

  function newSlide24 () {
    var slide24new = slides[23];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide24new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
  return newSlide26();
  }

  function newSlide26 () {
    var slide26new = slides[25];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide26new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
  return newSlide27();
  }

  function newSlide27 () {
    var slide27new = slides[26];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide27new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
  return newSlide28();
  }

  function newSlide28 () {
    var slide28new = slides[27];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide28new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
  return newSlide29();
  }

  function newSlide29 () {
    var slide29new = slides[28];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   slide29new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
  }








}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Yes, it's possible. If you need further help please show what you had tried and and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hey @Rubén, thanks for answering. I realize I should've asked how to do it as well. I added my code to the question if you can take a look. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for replying. When adding code, the best is to add a [mcve]. (there is no need to add all the functions that edit a single slide because they are copies slightly modified). What about your search efforts? Did you already review previous questions about doing replace text operations? P.S. The header and footer of a  presentation are set in the presentation master.

Comment: Hey, Yes I did review every resource out there and no one mentions footers and headers specifically as there both in the google docs class, not sheets. Apologies for the vagueness. it is my first ever coding project with no prior experience. so trying to figure things out one at a time. any help is appreciated.